# Deletar linhas que na coluna contem determinado valor

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Ola a todos estou tentando achar uma forma rápida para o seguinte processo, minha base tem 68000 linhas todas preenchidas, e com o passar do tempo ela vai aumentando, na minha coluna G tem os nomes das cidades, fiz um loop para encontrar o o nome da cidade que desejo excluir a linha, como são muitas linhas para procurar meu código se torna muito lento para terminar o processo, teria uma forma mais rápida de fazer esse processo? abaixo o código que estou usando.

```
Dim wwe As Worksheet
Dim Linha As Long
Dim ultima As Long

Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Limpar")
    ultima = w.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
With w
    For Linha = ultima To 2 Step -1
If Cells(Linha, "G") = "ABELARDO LUZ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ALAGOINHAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ALEXÂNIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ALFENAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ALMIRANTE TAMANDARÉ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ALTAMIRA DO PARANÁ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ALTO GARÇAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ALVORADA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ANÁPOLIS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ANTONINA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "APARECIDA DE GOIÂNIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ARACAJU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ARACRUZ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ARAPIRACA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ARAPORÃ" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "ARARAQUARA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ARAUCÁRIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ARUJÁ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ASSIS CHATEAUBRIAND" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ATIBAIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BALNEÁRIO CAMBORIÚ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BANDEIRANTES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BARBACENA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BARRA MANSA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BARUERI" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BAURU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BELÉM" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BELO HORIZONTE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BENTO GONÇALVES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BETIM" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "BIGUAÇU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BITURUNA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BLUMENAU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BOTUCATU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BRASILIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BRASÍLIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BRUMADINHO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BRUMADO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "BRUSQUE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CABEDELO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CABO FRIO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CACHOEIRA DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CACHOEIRINHA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CACHOEIRO DE ITAPEMIRIM" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CACULÉ" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAJATI" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CALDAS NOVAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMACAN" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMAÇARI" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMARAGIBE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMBORIÚ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMBUÍ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPINA GRANDE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPINA GRANDE DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPINAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPO BOM" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPO GRANDE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPO LARGO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAMPOS NOVOS" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "CANGUARETAMA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CANOAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAPÃO ALTO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAPITÃO LEÔNIDAS MARQUES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CARIACICA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CARUARU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAUCAIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CAXIAS DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CÉU AZUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CHAPECÓ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CIDADE OCIDENTAL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "COLATINA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "COLINAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "COLOMBO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CONCEIÇÃO DO JACUÍPE" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "CONCHAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CONCÓRDIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CONSELHEIRO LAFAIETE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CONSELHEIRO PENA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CONTAGEM" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CORONEL FABRICIANO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "COTIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CRICIÚMA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CUIABÁ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "CURITIBA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "DIVINÓPOLIS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "DOIS VIZINHOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "DOURADOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "DOUTOR ULYSSES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "DUQUE DE CAXIAS" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "ENTRE RIOS DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ERECHIM" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ESTÂNCIA VELHA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ESTEIO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "EUNÁPOLIS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "FARROUPILHA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "FAZENDA RIO GRANDE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "FEIRA DE SANTANA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "FLORIANÓPOLIS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "FORTALEZA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "FRANCISCO SÁ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GANDU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GARANHUNS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GASPAR" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GENERAL CÂMARA" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "GOIÂNIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GOIOERÊ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GOVERNADOR VALADARES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GRAVATÁ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GRAVATAÍ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GUAÍBA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GUAÍRA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GUAPORÉ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GUARAPARI" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GUARAPUAVA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GUARAREMA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GUARULHOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "GURINHÉM" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "IÇARA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "IGUATU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "IJUÍ" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "INDAIAL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "INDAIATUBA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "INDIARA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "IPATINGA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "IRAMAIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITABAIANA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITABAIANINHA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITABUNA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITAJAÍ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITAMARAJU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITAPEVA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITAQUIRAÍ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITAÚNA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "ITUMBIARA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "IVAIPORÃ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JABOATÃO DOS GUARARAPES" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "JABOTICABA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JACIARA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JARAGUÁ DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JATAÍ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JOAÇABA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JOÃO PESSOA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JOINVILLE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JUIZ DE FORA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JUNDIAÍ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JUQUITIBA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "JUTI" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "LAGES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "LAGUNA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "LAJEADO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "LAPA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "LAURO DE FREITAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "LINHARES" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "LORENA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "LUZIÂNIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MACAÉ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MACEIÓ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MAFRA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MANAUS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MANOEL RIBAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MARACANAÚ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MARILÂNDIA DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MAUÁ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MINEIROS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MOEDA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MOGI DAS CRUZES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MONTE CASTELO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MONTENEGRO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "MORRINHOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NATAL" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "NAVEGANTES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NILÓPOLIS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NITERÓI" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NOVA ALVORADA DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NOVA IGUAÇU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NOVA LIMA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NOVA VENEZA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "NOVO HAMBURGO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "OLINDA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "OSASCO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "OSÓRIO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PALHOÇA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PALMARES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PALMAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PARÁ DE MINAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PARACATU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PARANAGUÁ" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "PASSO FUNDO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PASSOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PATOS DE MINAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PAULISTA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PELOTAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PETROLINA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PICADA CAFÉ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PINHAIS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PIRACICABA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "POÇO DAS ANTAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "POÇOS DE CALDAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PONTA GROSSA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PONTE ALTA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PORTO ALEGRE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PORTO VELHO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "POUSO ALEGRE" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "PRAIA GRANDE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "PROTÁSIO ALVES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "QUATRO BARRAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "QUEDAS DO IGUAÇU" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RECIFE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIBEIRÃO PRETO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO BONITO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO BRANCO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO DAS OSTRAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO DE JANEIRO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO GRANDE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO LARGO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO PRETO DA EVA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO VERDE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RIO VERDE DE MATO GROSSO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "RONDONÓPOLIS" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "SALVADOR" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTA BÁRBARA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTA CECÍLIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTA CRUZ DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTA MARIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTA RITA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTA ROSA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTO ANDRE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTO ANDRÉ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTO ÂNGELO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTO ANTÔNIO DE JESUS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SANTOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO BENTO DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO BERNARDO DO CAMPO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO CRISTOVÃO DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO DOMINGOS" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO FRANCISCO DE PAULA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO GONÇALO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO GONÇALO DOS CAMPOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO JOAQUIM DA BARRA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO JOSÉ" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO JOSÉ DOS CAMPOS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO JOSÉ DOS PINHAIS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO LEOPOLDO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO LUÍS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO MATEUS DO SUL" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SAO PAULO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO PAULO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SÃO VICENTE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SAPIRANGA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SAPUCAIA DO SUL" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "SENADOR CANEDO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SERRA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SETE LAGOAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SIMÕES FILHO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SINOP" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SOROCABA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SOUSA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "SUZANO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TAGUATINGA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TEIXEIRA DE FREITAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TERESINA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TIMÓTEO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TORRES" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TRÊS DE MAIO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TRÊS PONTAS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TRINDADE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TRIUNFO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "TUBARÃO" Or _
    Cells(Linha, "G") = "UBERABA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "UBERLÂNDIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "URUGUAIANA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VACARIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VALPARAÍSO DE GOIÁS" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VARGINHA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VÁRZEA GRANDE" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VÁRZEA PAULISTA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VIAMÃO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VIÇOSA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VILA VELHA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VITÓRIA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VITÓRIA DA CONQUISTA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VITÓRIA DE SANTO ANTÃO" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VOLTA REDONDA" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "VOTORANTIM" Or Cells(Linha, "G") = "XANXERÊ" _
    Then
    .Rows(Linha).Delete
        End If
    Next Linha
End With
```

Comment: Você pode classificar os dados? Se puder classificar por ordem alfabética de cidade, fica BEM mais rápido e fácil excluir.

Comment: sim poderia, vou fazer o teste obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue aqui a minha sugestão de código para ajudar. Eu testei com uma planilha com 70 mil linhas e rodou em 3 minutos.

Cabe notar que eu fiz esse código partindo do princípio de que é preciso excluir as cidades que você mencionou acima e manter outras linhas referentes a outras eventuais cidades. Digo isso, pois, se fosse o caso de apagar a lista inteira da planilha, é mais fácil apagar tudo de uma vez.

Para funcionar, é preciso criar uma aba a mais (que, aqui, eu chamei de "Lista") com os nomes das cidades que precisam ser excluídas em cada célula (imagem abaixo) escritas exatamente como está no seu código, sendo que é possível remover e adicionar cidades nessa lista sem interferir no código.

[image: Aba Lista]

Já as linhas que contém os valores a serem excluídos estão na aba Base (imagem abaixo, com valores aleatórios para servir de exemplo), considerando que a lista de cidades está na coluna G.

[image: Aba Base]

Por fim, segue aqui:

```
Sub Remover_Cidades()

Dim W           As Worksheet
Dim WL          As Worksheet
Dim A           As Integer
Dim UltCel      As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Nomeia e seleciona as abas Base e Lista
Set W = Sheets("Base")

Set WL = Sheets("Lista")
WL.Select
WL.Range("A1").Select

'Mapeia qual é a última célula preenchida na aba Lista
Set UltCel = WL.Cells(WL.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

'Atribui o valor 1 ao contador que irá percorrer os valores na aba lista
A = 1

'Filtra os nomes das cidades na planilha Base de acordo com cada célula da Lista e exclui a linha
Do While A <= UltCel.Row
    
    W.Select
    W.Range("A$1:G$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=WL.Range("A" & A).Value
    W.Range("A$2:G$1048576").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    W.Range("$A$1:$G$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=7
    W.Range("A1").Select
        
    A = A + 1

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set W = Nothing
Set WL = Nothing
Set UltCel = Nothing

MsgBox "Pronto!", vbOKOnly, "Status"

End Sub
```

Se apresentar algum problema, me avise aqui.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas estou recebendo um erro nessa linha  `W.Range("A$1:G$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=WL.Range("A" & A).Value` "O método Range do objeto _Worksheet falhou", e por sinal as a minha coluna das cidades também e G.

Comment: me ajuda com amis essa ai por favor

Answer (score 0):

Poxa... por favor, você criou as planilhas auxiliares que eu mencionei na explicação?

Além disso, o código que eu passei você incorporou no código original ou inseriu em um módulo separado?

O ideal é inserir em um módulo separado, com o código todo e as abas auxiliares. Esse erro que você apontou costuma ocorrer quando algum intervalo não está definido no código.

Além disso, quando eu testei, não me ocorreu nenhum problema, mas pode ser que se sua planilha tem mais ou menos colunas do que o intervalo que eu especifiquei (A:G).

Certifique-se também que os nomes das abas auxiliares esteja exatamente ao do código. Se você não puder alterar na planilha do código.

Qualquer coisa, me chame aqui!